# Sitecore Landing Page Experience Editor on click logs out but works fine under content editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

Sitecore Landing Page Experience Editor on click logs out the user but experience editor works fine when we use it under content editor.

Sitecore version used :V 10.3.0

Log File :

```
35304 13:54:55 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Anonymous): Logout

35304 13:54:55 WARN  Protected page accessed with no current user
35304 13:54:55 WARN  Protected page accessed with no current user
35304 13:54:55 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.GotoLoginPage(HttpContext httpContext, Boolean returnAfterLogin)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.IsLoggedIn(Boolean returnAfterLogin)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.EnsureLoggedInForPreview.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Did you check this ? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19476/response-headers-error-when-trying-to-login-to-sitecore

Comment: Yes did check that , but i am not trying to login using http , its all https .

Comment: Do you have pipelines?

Comment: Yes , but we dont have any specific pipeline related to login mechanism.